# Esp8266 and uln2003 restarts

Tags: power-supply, darlington, esp8266

I am trying to drive 6 LEDs from an Esp8266 (esp201 break out board). Because of the Limit current of 12 mA the esp can do i want to use a  7way darlington Array to Power the LEDs.

I have programmed the esp for starters to blink only the gpios 4 and 5. No WiFi but Serial for debugging.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fl9JV0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Problem is that the esp restarts constantly. What i did to solve the Problem:

- exchange esp
- exchange uln
- used a soldered breadboard to ensure  connections
- used a 470 nf Elko between gnd and + 3.3
- exchange Power supply

Nothing changed. The only thing that does work is to power up the esp and After that connect the uln. Then everything works like a Charme.

I gues My Problem has something to do with Power surge at startup but i dont know how to overcome.

Comment: Please draw a schematic. It's very difficult to visualize your setup using just words.

Comment: You are right, i have altered my question.

Comment: 470nf won't cope with much of a power surge, try 100 uf on the 5V supply so the LDO doesn't drop out. Or, like, measure the supply rail noise on your scope.

Comment: Was the schematic updated? I don't see any caps at all. The ESP8266 will definitely need a large bank of capacitance across its power pins to deal with the power surges during transmission.

Comment: I tried numerous Caps up to 270µF with no change whatsoever. unfortunately I blew my Chip by connecting it directly to 5V by accident. Now I have a blister the exact sice of the esp on my Thumb ;-) So I can't test anything until I get new Chips. What I did that helped getting it to work a little better is inserting lots of yield() Operations into my code. Maybe my Problem is hogging the CPU.

Comment: Maybe could you post your code? Do you use the native toolchain, or the arduino framework port? I had a similar problem, I figured on later I was using too many Serial.print in loops. The watchdog timer was constantly engaging and resetting everything. yield() solved my problems.